# Unable to access EC2 instance from Windows OS either via OpenSSH or Bitvise

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ec2, openssh

Non-Tech newb here who uses Windows only. I have been trying to access my AWS EC2 instance from OpenSSH via WindowsOS. I got the .pem file in my laptop. Got Port 22 inbound rule enabled. Also changed the advanced security settings of my .pem file where I have disabled the inheritance and assigned my Windows email address as the sole user with full control. (screenshot below)

[image]

Yet I cannot get past the error  ***Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)***

[image]

I even tried running the following code and still getting the same error after attempting to connecting to the instance

```
$path = ".\my_pem_file.pem"
icacls.exe $path /reset
icacls.exe $path /GRANT:R "$($env:USERNAME):(R)"
icacls.exe $path /inheritance:r
```

For a change I tried to access the instance from Bitvise where I added the host as my ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx-compute-1.amazonaws.com Public IPv4 and username as ec2-user and port 22, yet still got the same error.

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What OS are you using in your EC2?

Comment: @Riz its a ubuntu instance in EC2 which I am trying to connect from Windows OS

Comment: Your username should be ubuntu and not ec2-user.

Comment: I stand corrected, its a linux instance. So I guess the username should be ec2user. Yet its still not helping

Comment: I think you mean 'amazon linux' and not just 'linux'. Have you tried to login via ssm and see the logs with `tail -f /var/log/secure` while trying to login with your key pair?